# Measuring the overlap between two probability distribution

Tags: distance, probability, probability-density, probability-distribution

I have many probability distributions, I need to compute **the amount of overlap between two probability distributions**. I don't know the type of distribution since it really depends on the data itself.

[image]

My question is what appropriate approach that should I use for this case?

Comment: Interesting question. Cross-entropy and Kullback-Leibler divergence (also an entropy) are a couple of ways to quantify "overlap". Further discussion is suitable for stats.stackexchange.com instead of SO.

Comment: Thanks mate, i'll move to stats stack exchange

Comment: Or perhaps you could provide some sample data and code based on @RobertDodier.